# How to catch a signal in a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a kernel module that has a while(1) loop in the init routine that is supposed to run infinitely.

If I have an equivalent code in a user space program, when I press Control+C the user space program is terminated, however this is not the case for a kernel module.

Is there a way to send a kill signal to the kernel module (when it is still running its init routine) so it can terminate / exit ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In kernel you may use `signal_pending()` or `fatal_signal_pending()` for check whether signal/fatal signal is arrived:

```
while(!fatal_signal_pending(current) {
    // infinite loop
}
```

So, you may press Control+C for `insmod <your-module.ko>`, and module's init function will terminate the loop.

---

**Kernel thread** (created with `kthread_create()` or similar) may catch signals only if it allows them with `allow_signal()`